# Is there any need of EMC/EMI shielding of LCD used for Aviation pruposes?

Tags: lcd, emc

We have a TFEL technology display which uses Indium tin oxide (ITO) Coating for EMC/EMI shielding. Now we want to replace it with newer LCD TFT display. the question is would ITO coating is needed for LCD EMC/EMI shielding?

Comment: If we don't know what display it is and how much it radiates, how can we answer if it radiates too much or not? Is the device even approved for aviation use?

Comment: The devil is in the detail.

Answer (score 0):

> Now we want to replace it with newer LCD TFT display. the question is
> would ITO coating is needed for LCD EMC/EMI shielding?

You'll have to do a test, replace the TFEL and run it through any regulatory testing that the LCD is regulated by. If it doesn't pass and emits too much radiation, then you'll need to use better shielding